# Word for attracting attention

Tags: word-request

Consider a sentence like:

> Because of ..., personalization methods are brought into attention.

I want to state that because of some events or reasons, people (or for example researchers) became interested in the topic and started developing or using it. However, I'm not sure what word to use for it. My inner feeling is that "is brought into attention" is a good choice but didn't find it in the dictionaries. Also, about "bring sth to one's attention", [this](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+to+attention) states that it means "To inform one of something", which doesn't look like what I mean. "Attracting attention" may also not be fit for the purpose because the methods are not doing something (attracting attention), instead some other things cause people to pay attention to them. What's the best choice for that?

Comment: "I was/became interested in [something] and researched the topic."

Comment: X is attracting the attention of academics.

Comment: @Lambie What if we don't want to mention the group (e.g., academics)? Moreover, something more powerful such that when the reader reads it feels a strong feeling towards X, not just simply attracting attention. Maybe a great amount of change before and after being brought into attention happens.

Answer (score 1):

A common expression is to *come to the attention of [someone]*

> For [some reason] personalization methods **have come to the attention** of researchers.

Another possibility is this variation on your original:

> For [some reason] personalization methods **have been brought to the attention** of researchers.

Note this uses the passive voice.  If you want to specify the actor who did the *bringing*, you can change it to active voice:

> For [some reason], [some entity] **brought** personalization methods **to the attention** of researchers.

However, the subject matter suggests that researchers became interested after learning about the methods from various sources, and that these details are not important.  In this case it's common to use the passive voice.  Another example:

> The government decided to make changes to the existing law after various loopholes **were brought** to their attention

And an example where the active voice is probably better:

> After I found out my son was being regularly bullied after school, **I** immediately **brought** this to the attention of school authorities.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach the sample sentence could be along these lines:

"Because of ..., X methods become/became/have become/may become... the focus of attention."

Here's a less vague, more specific example:

"Because of the upsurge in terrorist activity, harsher interrogation methods have become the focus of attention."